# Keeping code DRY in Rails with Better ActiveRecord commands and Arrays, Hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Let's take a looks at this current code, it works but it is not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

```
def create_key_performance_indicators
  organization_aco = Organization.find_by_name('ACO').id
  KeyPerformanceIndicator.where(name: 'ED Visits per 1,000').first_or_create(
    target: 100,
    organization_id: organization_aco
  )
  KeyPerformanceIndicator.where(name: 'Average Length of Stay').first_or_create(
    target: 5,
    organization_id: organization_aco
  )
  KeyPerformanceIndicator.where(name: 'Admits per 1,000').first_or_create(
    target: 100,
    organization_id: organization_aco
  )
end
```

So there is a table called **KeyPerformanceIndicators** that has a foreign key with organization_id fields to the **Organization** table.

Well first thing to clean up is that three times copy-paste of `KeyPerformanceIndictor.where` command, perhaps we can put those values somehow in an array or a hash, etc...and just loop through them inside this method.  But I am just very new to all this language and syntax, How can I achieve this? or also if you have better ideas to achieve this all are much welcome and appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
def create_key_performance_indicators
  organization_aco = Organization.find_by_name('ACO').id
  [
    [ 'ED Visits per 1,000'    , 100 ] ,
    [ 'Average Length of Stay' , 5   ] ,
    [ 'Admits per 1,000'       , 100 ]
  ].each do |name, target|
      KeyPerformanceIndicator.where(name: name).first_or_create(
        target: target,
        organization_id: organization_aco
      )
  end
end
```

Comment: I see that this is basically the same as cthulu's answer previously posted. cthulu answered first, so presumably deserves the checkmark (if errors are corrected there).

Comment: nice... Can you somehow take out those three lines of arrays of array and put them out in a separate variable? so we can just use the name of that variable before ".each" ?

Comment: @bdota, of course. Just say `myvar = [...]` and then `myvar.each do |name, target| ...`. That would be a good thing to do if the variable name helps explain what the code is doing or if the same array would be used in other code as well.

Comment: hmm...but in the second line of his code, he is passing the name of the first array only. see my comments under his post.

Comment: awesome, we made great progress.  Last thing that bothers me is the first line of our code that is ID for organization "ACO" .. I am thinking well if I want to have more organizations and insert some stuff for them too then again we will have core repeating :(  Any suggestions for that part?  I will mark your answer as accepted anyway, but was wondering if you have suggestions for that part too. Thanks.

Comment: First, you make the code work, and then see what kind of repetition patterns you have to factor out. It's counterproductive to plan ahead for kinds of repetition you don't have yet -- you just end up with more complex code to handle conditions that might or might not ever exist. Generally, aim for the simplest code that does what you need now, and refactor again later when what you need "now" has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/cthulhu666/4972937

Comment: thanks but I think in the WHERE clause you are just accessing the first aaray...so the other two won't be inserted in the table?

Comment: and also: what happened to organization_id ?